# Custom cell class in UITableView with static cells

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, storyboard

I have a UITableView with static cells in a Storyboard. The static cells are of a custom class. I would like to wire up the outlets for the cell but it seems like this is not supported?

Wiring the views onto the ViewController works, but is rather messy (there are lots of cells). A workaround would probably also be to tag the views, but also not ideal. Any other ideas?

[image]

Comment: Instead of doing this you can create the custom cell and add the button,image,label,textfield...in custom cell and you can call the custom cell with storyboard through the importing .h of custom cell and registering the custom cell.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot control-drag your UIView to the source file. However, you can link up the other way around.

1. In Storyboard, select your static cell, and setup the `Custom Class`.
2. In your custom class, add all the `@IBOutlet` as you need.
3. Go back to Storyboard, select your static cell, and in Inspector, select `Show the Connections Inspector` (the last tab).
4. Drag the Outlets there to your UIView(s).

If you use "assistant editor", you will see the circle in front of @IBOutlet is now filled (hooked).

Answer (score -1):

have you checked custom class of that UITableViewCell. it should be custom file and subclass of UITableviewCell you are created.